# fedora : install package from local, with no internet access

Tags: fedora, package-management

Is there a way to install a downloaded package on a fresh install of fedora 33 without triggering cache update, as the server does not have internet access (vm guest) ?

I tried the --cacheonly option, set the metadata value to -1 for the set-opt option (dnf) : neither seems to function.

Thank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that your system doesn’t have Internet access (which I assume means no access to the package repositories), you could forgo `dnf` entirely:

```
rpm -i yourpackage.rpm
```

`dnf` would resolve missing dependencies for you, but that’s not going to work anyway if the system can’t access the necessary repositories. If other packages are needed, you’ll have to download them yourself and add them to the `rpm -i` command.